# Matter.js doesn't update body properties if Pixi.js renderer is used

Tags: pixi.js, matter.js

I want to update certain body properties if user clicks on it, e.g. `body.render.lineWidth = 5;`
It works just fine if the default canvas renderer is used. If I switch to Pixi.js renderer it stops working and doesn't seem to reflect any properties at all.
I also tried with the `Matter.Body.set` function but with no luck either. Properties **are** set actually to a body but the body keeps showing the initial style which was provided at the construction time.

What is the proper way to set those properties?

sample.js

```
var Engine = Matter.Engine,
    World = Matter.World,
    Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
    Common = Matter.Common,
    MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

var createOptions = function(options) {
    var defaults = {
        isManual: false,
        sceneName: 'mixed',
        sceneEvents: []
    };
    return Common.extend(defaults, options);
};

var options = {
    positionIterations: 6,
    velocityIterations: 4,
    enableSleeping: false,
    metrics: { extended: true },
    render: {
        controller: Matter.RenderPixi
    }
};

var engine = Engine.create(document.getElementById('canvas-container'), createOptions(options));
var world = engine.world;

var mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
    constraint: {
    render: {
      visible: false
    }
  }
});
World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);

World.add(world, [
    Bodies.rectangle(400, 0, 800, 1, { isStatic: true }),
    Bodies.rectangle(400, 600, 800, 1, { isStatic: true }),
    Bodies.rectangle(800, 300, 1, 600, { isStatic: true }),
    Bodies.rectangle(0, 300, 1, 600, { isStatic: true })
]);

var body = Bodies.polygon(200, 200, 4, Common.random(50, 60), {
    isStatic: true,
    friction: 1,
    render: {
        fillStyle: '#f0f0f0',
        strokeStyle: 'black',
        lineWidth: 1
    }
});

World.add(world, body);

Matter.Events.on(mouseConstraint, 'mousedown', function(e) {
    body.render.lineWidth = 5;
});

var renderOptions = engine.render.options;
renderOptions.wireframes = false;
renderOptions.hasBounds = false;
renderOptions.showDebug = false;
renderOptions.showBroadphase = false;
renderOptions.showBounds = false;
renderOptions.showVelocity = false;
renderOptions.showCollisions = false;
renderOptions.showAxes = false;
renderOptions.showPositions = false;
renderOptions.showAngleIndicator = false;
renderOptions.showIds = false;
renderOptions.showShadows = false;
renderOptions.showVertexNumbers = false;
renderOptions.showConvexHulls = false;
renderOptions.showInternalEdges = false;
renderOptions.showSeparations = false;
renderOptions.background = '#fff';

Engine.run(engine);
```

sample.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas-container"></div>
  <script src="pixi.min.v3.0.10.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="matter.min.v0.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="sample.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I comment out `controller: Matter.RenderPixi` everything works OK.

Comment: I have no experience on matter.js, but if possible you could at least provide some code to show this. Just to note, you are using / looking at the correct "custom" renderer and canvas that PIXI.js creates on construction and not some other on the DOM, that actually isn't the one manipulated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RenderPixi creates primitives only once when the body first gets rendered and this gets cached.
To remove it from the cache, you should be able to do something like:

```
engine.render.primitives['b-' + body.id] = null;
```

Then it should get created again.