# How to user Matter.js in pixi.js project?

Tags: pixi.js, matter.js

I made a BallCabin with Matter.js in DOM (render BallCabin on div element), it perform OK. But same code, when I put it into pixi.js project, I found nothing is displayed. I'd like to how can I render Matter.js in pixi.js project. Sorry for poor English... and thanks for all reply!

The following is my code:

1. window.game.view is the root element (canvas) in pixi program (reference for Application.view), I thought I may render BallCabin on the canvas.
2. Ticker.shared.add(this.update, this) to call update function.

```
export class BallCabin extends Sprite{
  constructor() {
    super();

    this._world = null;
    this._engine = null;
    this._cabin = null;
    this._balls = [];

    this.BALL_RADIUS = 12;

    this.initView();
  }

  initView() {
    this.initScene();
    this.makeCabin();
    this.makeSensors();
    this.makeBalls();
    this.initAction();
  }

  initScene() {
    const element = window.game.view;

    this._engine = Engine.create();
    let runner = Runner.create();
    let render = Render.create({
      background: '#6eb543',
      element: element,
      engine: this._engine,
      options: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        background: 'transparent',
        wireframes: false,
        showIds: false
      }
    });
    this._world = this._engine.world;

    Render.run(render);
    Runner.run(runner, this._engine);
  }

  initAction() {
    Events.on(this._engine, 'collisionStart', (evt) => this.onCollision(evt));
    Ticker.shared.add(this.update, this);
  }

  makeCabin() {
    let parts = [];
    let pt = {x: 150, y: 150};

    for (let i = 0; i < 90; i++) {
      let x = pt.x + Math.cos(i * 4 * Math.PI / 180) * 120;
      let y = pt.y + Math.sin(i * 4 * Math.PI / 180) * 120;
      let options = {friction: 0.5, angle: Math.PI / 180 * i * 4, render: {fillStyle: i !== 0 ? '#2E2D34' : '#FFFFFF'}};
      let rec = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 10, 12, options);
      parts.push(rec);
      Composite.add(this._world, rec);
    }

    this._cabin = Body.create({parts, isStatic: true});
  }

  makeSensors() {
    const pt = {x: 150, y: 150};
    const ary = [];

    for (let i = 20; i < 45; i++) {
      const x = pt.x + Math.cos(i * 4 * Math.PI / 180) * 120;
      const y = pt.y + Math.sin(i * 4 * Math.PI / 180) * 120;
      const render = {strokeStyle: '#C44D58', fillStyle: 'transparent', lineWidth: 1};
      const options = {isSensor: true, isStatic: true, friction: 0, label: 'addSpeedSensor', angle: Math.PI / 180 * i * 4, render: render};

      let rec = Bodies.rectangle(x, y, 30, 30, options);
      ary.push(rec);
      Composite.add(this._world, rec);
    }
  }

  makeBalls() {
    let pt = {x: 150, y: 150};

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let x = pt.x - 65 + i * 5;
      let y = pt.y - 65 + i * 5;
      let options = {isStatic: false, mass: 1 + i * 2, friction: 0, frictionStatic: 0, label: 'ball', render: {opacity: 0.6,}, collisionFilter: {category: 0x0002, mask: 0x0002 | 0x0001}};

      const ball = Bodies.circle(x, y, this.BALL_RADIUS, options);
      this._balls.push(ball);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
      let x = pt.x - 65 + i * 5;
      let y = pt.y - 65 + i * 5;
      let options = {isStatic: false, mass: 1 + i * 2, friction: 0, frictionStatic: 0, label: 'ball', render: {opacity: 1,}, collisionFilter: {category: 0x0004, mask: 0x0004 | 0x0001}};

      const ball = Bodies.circle(x, y, this.BALL_RADIUS, options);
      this._balls.push(ball);
    }
    Composite.add(this._world, this._balls);
  }

  onCollision(evt) {
    let pairs = evt.pairs;
    for (let i = 0, j = pairs.length; i != j; ++i) {
      let pair = pairs[i];
      let {bodyA, bodyB} = pair;

      if (bodyA.label === 'addSpeedSensor') {
        Body.setVelocity(bodyB, {x: -6, y: -5});
        //Body.applyForce(bodyB, bodyB.position, {x: 0.3, y: 0.5})
      } else if (bodyB.label === 'addSpeedSensor') {
        // Body.applyForce(bodyA, {x: bodyA.position.x, y: bodyA.position.y}, {x: -0.1, y: -0.05})
      }
    }
  }

  update(deltaTime) {
    //super.update(delta);
    if (this._cabin) {
      Body.rotate(this._cabin, Math.PI / 120);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know anything about pixi, but looks like you're using the MJS internal renderer. Just a guess, but I imagine you'll want to use pixi as the renderer, which means running MJS headlessly (as a pure physics engine, not a renderer). I have many examples of how to do this with other renderers like p5, React, HTML5 canvas and the DOM, so I imagine you'll be able to plug in pixi with a few small modifications. Take [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906218/using-matter-js-to-render-to-the-dom-or-react/65354225#65354225) for example.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, when you find yourself stuck while merging libraries together, it's best to work with minimal examples. Once you get the basic idea of how to integrate the libraries, you can apply the simple example to your larger project.

In the approach I'll outline below, the Matter.js `Render` class will not be used. Pixi.js is the renderer; MJS is only used for headless physics. See [Using Matter.js to render to the DOM or React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63906218/using-matter-js-to-render-to-the-dom-or-react/65354225#65354225) for an overview and examples of using different rendering front-ends with Matter.js. I've adapted the same strategy from that thread to Pixi.

Here's a minimal example integrating the two libraries to get you started:

```js
// Matter.js
const engine = Matter.Engine.create();
const box = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(150, 0, 50, 50); // x y w h
const ground = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(
  // x   y    w    h    options
  200, 200, 400, 120, {isStatic: true}
);
const mouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint.create(
  engine, {element: document.body}
);
Matter.Composite.add(engine.world, [box, ground, mouseConstraint]);

// Pixi.js
const app = new PIXI.Application({width: 640, height: 360});
document.body.appendChild(app.view);
const boxSprite = PIXI.Sprite.from("https://picsum.photos/50/50");
const groundSprite = PIXI.Sprite.from("https://picsum.photos/400/120");
boxSprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
groundSprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
app.stage.addChild(boxSprite);
app.stage.addChild(groundSprite);
app.ticker.add((delta) => {
  boxSprite.rotation = box.angle;
  boxSprite.x = box.position.x;
  boxSprite.y = box.position.y;
  groundSprite.x = ground.position.x;
  groundSprite.y = ground.position.y;
  Matter.Engine.update(engine, delta * (1000 / 60));
});
```

```css
body {margin: 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pixi.js/7.3.2/pixi.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.min.js"></script>
```

I've used Pixi's `sprite.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5)` method to center the sprite rendering offsets to match the MJS bodies. This makes updates pretty easy for this case: simply set the Pixi sprite positions to be whatever the MJS body positions are.

I'm passing Pixi's `delta` into MJS with a 60 FPS interval multiplier, which seems to replicate MJS's runner speed on my 60hz monitor. You can omit this parameter or modify it to fit your needs. Or you can use Matter's runner, or a [custom update loop](https://github.com/pixijs/pixijs/wiki/v5-Custom-Application-GameLoop#custom-gameloop), instead of Pixi's.

Finally, for simplicity, this example doesn't pre-load assets, so they may not render immediately. See [assets](https://pixijs.com/guides/components/assets#loading-multiple-assets) in the Pixi docs to ensure your assets are loaded before the animation starts.

---

Other approaches are possible. See:

- [Matter x Pixi JS by Celso White on Codepen](https://codepen.io/celsowhite/pen/XWbEzpx?editors=0010)
- [`RenderPixi`](https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/RenderPixi.html), a built-in but deprecated MJS module for integrating with Pixi
- [Matter.js doesn't update body properties if Pixi.js renderer is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36236288/matter-js-doesnt-update-body-properties-if-pixi-js-renderer-is-used)